# html 1.13 package installation

Tags: python, html, python-module, pythonpath

I downloaded html 1.13 package from [Python site](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/html) and as per instructions I doubleclicked on `install.bat` and installed it. I also added the directory `C:\Python26\HTML.py-0.04` to `PYTHONPATH`. But when I try to import the module with

```
>>> from html import HTML
```

I still get  `ImportError: No module named html` Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The download html-1.13.tar.gz does not contain install.bat. It how ever contains setup.py. You can install it by running the following on command line: python setup.py install

Comment: @pyfunc: Thanks again. As I mentioned below, there was another html package there and I untar that by mistake. I installed it with setup.py install and it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual installation issues.

> Issue

you don't need to add it to PYTHONPATH if it is installed into standard directory site-packages and it would already be in the path.

check out there should be a html.. folder in default search path : lib\site-packages

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\

If you find the folder then your import should work automatically. If you do not find it, that means it did not install properly. To see your issues, run install.bat from command line and check out the errors.

> About PYTHONPATH

It augments the default search path for module files. This is usually when, you do not want to install and simply point to custom directory so that python can import modules from there.

> Read

- http://docs.python.org/install/
- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: thanks! I'll save this answer for reference. I had a previous html.py in site-packages maybe that's why it was not installing. I deleted that and it works now.